# How to add a chart created in code behind to the rendered html page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm trying to create a .net charting control completely in the code behind and insert that chart at a specific location on the web page.

Here is my html page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="chart"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //SET UP THE DATA TO PLOT  
        double[] yVal = { 80, 20 };
        string[] xName = { "Pass", "Fail" };

      //CREATE THE CHART
        Chart Chart1 = new Chart();

      //BIND THE DATA TO THE CHART
        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xName, yVal);

      //SET THE CHART TYPE TO BE PIE
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
        Chart1.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
        Chart1.Series[0]["PieStartAngle"] = "-90";

      //SET THE COLOR PALETTE FOR THE CHART TO BE A PRESET OF NONE 
      //DEFINE OUR OWN COLOR PALETTE FOR THE CHART 
        Chart1.Palette = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.None;
        Chart1.PaletteCustomColors = new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Red };

      //SET THE IMAGE OUTPUT TYPE TO BE JPEG
        Chart1.ImageType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageType.Jpeg;

      //ADD A PLACE HOLDER CHART AREA TO THE CHART
      //SET THE CHART AREA TO BE 3D
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

      //ADD A PLACE HOLDER LEGEND TO THE CHART
      //DISABLE THE LEGEND
        Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
        Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I want to render the charting control inside the div with id="chart"

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you installed the charting framework without any hitches:-

View:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="chart"></div>
        <asp:Chart id="Chart1" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind:-

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //SET UP THE DATA TO PLOT  
        double[] yVal = { 80, 20 };
        string[] xName = { "Pass", "Fail" };

      //CREATE THE CHART
        // Don't need to create the chart because it's a control!

      //BIND THE DATA TO THE CHART
        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xName, yVal);

      //SET THE CHART TYPE TO BE PIE
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
        Chart1.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
        Chart1.Series[0]["PieStartAngle"] = "-90";

      //SET THE COLOR PALETTE FOR THE CHART TO BE A PRESET OF NONE 
      //DEFINE OUR OWN COLOR PALETTE FOR THE CHART 
        Chart1.Palette = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.None;
        Chart1.PaletteCustomColors = new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Red };

      //SET THE IMAGE OUTPUT TYPE TO BE JPEG
        Chart1.ImageType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageType.Jpeg;

      //ADD A PLACE HOLDER CHART AREA TO THE CHART
      //SET THE CHART AREA TO BE 3D
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

      //ADD A PLACE HOLDER LEGEND TO THE CHART
      //DISABLE THE LEGEND
        Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
        Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Check out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Comment: @Iain: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to do it w/o actually having the asp:chart tag in the aspx page.

Comment: @Ryan: If it's really necessary, you could use a Literal in the aspx page and use Chart.RenderControl to set its text property, but I don't really see the point. Any particular reason why you need to do it all in the codebehind?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

Why the dynamic rendering approach?  Why not just define the tag as:

And set the attributes on the control?  Alternatively, you could try putting a  and setting the text as the rendered response, which will wrap it with a span.  You could try out other controls to do this with if you get an error with that, like LiteralControl.

Comment: @Brian: How would I apply the answer you specified to the code I have above. I'm fairly new to using .NET... I'm slowly trying to train myself to use .NET as opposed to classic ASP. It's very important that I'm able to render the chart at the specific location on the web page. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you were talking MVC... I apologize.  I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try
put in aspx:

```
div id="chart" runat="server"
```

in the code:

```
this.chart.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

my case i need create more than one with data from datatable.